MessageBox using Win32 API , the content is obscure or some aliasing
I am a beginner for Win32 development.So I wrote the code below:
int code = MessageBox(0, L"Notation", L"Alarm", MB_OKCANCEL);

and it showed below:

My question is why the content string "Notation" is obscure, or not clearly as the tile "Alarm"?

use manifest to link with comctrl 6.0 version

Your program is not DPI-aware, so it renders text ("Notation") at low resolution that is then rescaled to match the screen DPI. The title bar, on the other hand, is rendered by the system at full resolution, so it doesn't look blurry.
